# Django prefetch_related with FK into a view

Tags: python, html, django

I am following the Django official site tutorial for the polls app and after finish it I am working in some improvement to acquire more knowledge about Django.

My first purpose is to change the view to show all questions and possible answers to it.

The **models** are:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publication_date=models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.publication_date <= now

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'publication_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    question=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

As you can see 1 choice is related to 1 question.

In the view I am able to render all the questions, all the choices, but not a question and his choices. To do that I tried the following:

**View**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Choice,Question
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'surveys/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'question_choice_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
return Choice.objects.all().prefetch_related('question')
```

**html**:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'surveys/style.css' %}" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if question_choice_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question_choice_pair in question_choice_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'surveys:detail' question_choice_pair.question.id %}">{{ question_choice_pair.question.distinct.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% if question_choice_pair %}
         <ul>
            {% for choice in question_choice_list %}
                <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
         </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No answers are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No questions are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to find a method to get the `distinct question_text` on `question_choice_list` but no way. I thought to try it with two queries, 1 to get all questions. And then while render the question querying the coices for that question id. But before trying anything that can teach me some bad practices I would like to know how to solve that with the best possible practice and why to do it that way.

¿Is it my approach far of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all of the related choices for a question, you will need to do the following:

```
questions = Question.objects.prefetch_related('choice_set').all()
```

Also you should not do this:

```
Choice.objects.prefetch_related('question').all()
```

Instead you should do this:

```
Choice.objects.select_related('question').all()
```

See [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for `select_related` and `prefetch_related`

Comment: Great answer. Thanks @user4426017